# Infragistics: How to show multiple ignite Snackbar using id

Tags: angular, infragistics, snackbar, ignite-ui-angular

I want to show multiple Snackbar on the angular website. I am using ignite UI for angular and using Snackbar from ignite.

```
<igx-snackbar id="snackbar1" [displayTime]="displayTime">
  <div [class]="leftBorder"></div>
  <div class="snackbar-detail">
    <img [class]="iconType" [alt]="('LBL_CLOSE' | translate)" [src]="iconPath">
    <div class="message-section">
      <div class="snackbar-title">{{messageTitle}}</div>
      <div class="snackbar-message">{{messageDesc}}</div>
    </div>
    <img (click)="closeSnackbar()" class="close-icon" [alt]="('LBL_CLOSE' | translate)"
      src="assets/icons/essentials/close.svg">
  </div>
</igx-snackbar>
```

I am able to show the snacbar using

```
 @ViewChild(IgxSnackbarComponent, { static: true }) public igxSnackBar: IgxSnackbarComponent;

 this.igxSnackBar.show();
```

but I want to show another snackbar so I have added `id="snackbar1"` and able to get the id using

```
let snackbarId = this.igxSnackBar.id;
console.log(snackbarId);
```

but I am not able to open the particular snackbar using the id.

can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you use a specific [@ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description) selector for each of the [Snackbar components](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/snackbar). You can use a template reference variable:

```html
<igx-snackbar #snackbar1 [autoHide]="false" actionText="CLOSE" (clicked)="close(snackbar1)">Message sent</igx-snackbar>
```

..

A template reference variable 'snackbar1'

```
@ViewChild('snackbar1', { static: true }) public igxSnackBar: IgxSnackbarComponent;
```

With the current implementation that you shared the change detector will look for the first Snackbar in the DOM.

Using of show() method is deprecated in the newer versions, use [open()](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/docs/typescript/latest/classes/IgxSnackbarComponent.html#open) instead.